# define const list

Tags: c++, stl

I do something like this and get errors from compiler

```
using namespace std;

///define a method for list
void method(const list<int>&lst) //ERROR here
{
  //do something
}
```

I have no idea why

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you provide more contextual information? Did you include the list header with #include <list>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <list>
```

Comment: This is best answer! I vote your reply as a final answer but a box tells me that I can only vote you after 8 minutes. Thank you everybody for your posts.